# Spark (pyspark) overwrite the table in teradata using JDBC with string column length (varchar(255)). It is not allowing more than 255 string length

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, teradata

When I write ("overwrite") spark dataframe into teradata via JDBC, the string fields are created with only 255 characters length even though the source has more than that. I request someone please what i should take place to allow more than 255 character length when it overwrites the data in to teradata.

I tried to load google bigquery table data (source) into teradata using pyspark with JDBC source driver, bigquery table had string fields having 1024 in length. after pyspark had overwritten the data into teradata, i saw the string fields created with only varchar(255).

I expected to load the table with varchar(1024). Someone please advise my query

Comment: How are the columns in the target table defined?

Comment: After write ("overwrite" mode) the dataframe into teradata. The string columns are defined VARCHAR(255). My expectation is VARCHAR(1024).

Comment: are you creating the table as part of the spark job, or is it a pre-existing table?  If it's a pre-existing table, then the answer is pretty clear, alter the columns to be the appropriate size.  Test in a pre-production environment, etc...

Comment: It is not pre-existing table. I am newly creating the table with overwrite mode.

Comment: I **think** you can control this with `...write..option("createTableColumnTypes",<column name>, datatype...`,  but I would suggest creating the table once, truncating the table separately, and then inserting into it, instead of using insert overwrite.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I will try the above suggestion. If it doesn't work as expected, I do create the table, truncate when i do write the data into it.